# Is there a way to determine my network transportation to specific path?

Tags: routing, router, network, networking, route

How can I determine my network transportation to specific path. I would like to determine that my data packages will go through specific routers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TLDR you can't.**

You can use [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) to see the path a packet will likely take from your computer to a remote one, however, the very nature of the Internet is that a packet can take any path between two computers, depending on router availability, link failures or congestion, or router specific configuration.

Two packets from the same flow could take different pathes, or you could even have ICMP packets (from a traceroute for example) taking a path while other packets (TCP) actually passing through different routers.

There's nothing you can do about it for networks that are not under your control.

Originally, two options (`loose source routing`and `strict source routing`, see [RFC791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1)) were present in IP that were supposed to allow you to specify which routers a packet should/must go through but it was never used on the Internet and this option is totally ignored by most (if not all) routers.